# Java Generic of Another generic

Tags: java, generics, dao

I have interface:

```
interface Identifable<T extends Serializable> {
      T getID();
}
```

and class that implement this:

```
public class Cat implements Identifable<Long> {
       public Long getID(){...};
}
```

everything works fine. so far. Now I want to create GenericDAO, why I cannot create this?:

```
public abstract GenericDAO<T extends Identifable<S>> {
    T getByID(S id);
}
```

I can only declare my GenericDAO as this:

```
public abstract GenericDAO<T extends Identifable, S> {
  T getById(S id);
}
```

And complete class:

```
public CatDAO extends GenericDAO<Cat, Long> {
      Cat getById(Long id);
}
```

But i think it's useless, because I repeat information. I already declared, that Cat implements Identifable< Long >, so why do I must declare GenericDAO< Cat, Long >, not just GenericDAO< Cat > ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, every generic type must be specified. You can go without specifying any type, but you can't go without specifying just one.

Also, **every** generic type must be specified in the declaration. If you want to have `class GenericDAO<T extends Identifable<U>>`, you must add the generic type declaration for `U` to your class declaration like this (since `U` is actually a generic type here):

```
public abstract class GenericDAO<T extends Identifable<U>, U>
```

The following is partially off-topic, but you might find it useful.

I've noticed that in your definition of `GenericDAO` two generic types are not tied to each other. This might not be what you want.

What you have here is a particular case in which the two generics are matching (the `Long` type in the `Cat` and `CatDAO` definitions). Consider having these declarations:

```
public class Dog implements Identifable<Long>
public class DogDAO extends GenericDao<Dog, String>
```

This would force you to write the `getById` method in `DogDAO` method:

```
Dog getById(String id);
```

Your `getId` method in the `Dog` returns a `Long` so your `getById` method int `DogDAO` would have to compare `String`s to `Long`s. This is valid thing to do, but it's a bit counter-intuitive. Having a `getById` method for `DogDAO` that takes a `Long` parameter makes more sense, since the `Dog`s IDs are actually `Long`s.

If you want to tie the two types together, you can define the `GenericDAO` class as:

```
public abstract class GenericDAO<T extends Identifable<S>, S>
```

You still have to specify the second parameter, but at least the compiler can help you make sure that the types are matching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public abstract class GenericDAO<S extends Serializable, T extends Identifable<S>> {
    abstract T getByID(S id);
}
```

Comment: I think he already knows that this works, but you haven't answered his question.