# Java - Replace interface type for implementation type with bounded type parameters

Tags: java, generics, interface, bounded-types, f-bounded-polymorphism

I'm trying to learn functional programming with Haskell but I'm struggling to understand some concepts. I thought it would be a good idea to translate some of those concepts to Java since it's the language I feel the most comfortable with.

I have the following interface `Applicative<A>`:

```
public interface Applicative<A>
{
    public <B> Applicative<B> pure (B value);

    public <B> Applicative<B> apply (Applicative<Function<A, B>> applicative);

    public <B, C> Function<Applicative<B>, Applicative<C>> liftA2 (
        Function<A, Function<B, C>> function);
}
```

Let's say I have an implementation of the interface `ListApplicative<A>`. It extends `ArrayList<A>` and it implements `Applicative<A>`.

**The question is:** How do I turn all the `Applicative<?>` into `ListApplicative<?>`? Is it even possible? Are there any hacks to do it?

```
public class ListApplicative<A> extends ArrayList<A> implements Applicative<A>
{
    @Override
    public <B> ListApplicative<B> pure (B value)
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    @Override
    public <B> ListApplicative<B> apply (
        ListApplicative<Function<A, B>> applicative)
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    @Override
    public <B, C> Function<ListApplicative<B>, ListApplicative<C>> liftA2 (
        Function<A, Function<B, C>> function)
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

I've read a little bit about F-bound types, but I'm not sure what to do. I can't use `B` or `C` as parameterized types since their types are unknown until you run the function.

I've looked at other similar questions like [this one about functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440453/java-f-bound-types-with-generics), [this one about generics of generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677077/java-generic-of-another-generic) and [this one about interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407882/enforcing-return-type-for-an-class-that-implements-an-interface) but I didn't find the answer I was looking for.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you want to turn ```Applicative<?>``` to ```ListApplicative<?>```? Your interface is designed to deal with ```Applicative<?>``` so you must guarantee that all your class which implement ```Applicative<?>``` can deal with ```Applicative<?>``` instead of just ```ListApplicative<?>```. If you really want to do that then you should not use an interface, just write those methods in your ```ListApplicative<?>``` class.

Comment: I've heard the comparison between Haskell type classes and Java interfaces so I thought it would be a good approach.

Comment: Sorry I don't know much of Haskell. As far as I know you can't do this in Java, it is not the problem of generics or type classes but it violates the main idea of ```interface```. You can use ```instanceof``` to check whether an ```Applicative<?>``` is a ```ListApplicative<?>```, and you can also return a ```ListApplicative<?>``` as an ```Applicative<?>```, but with this approach you won't get the benefit of static compile checks.